# String: replace a line which contains a word

Tags: c#

I have a string copied from a mutiline text box. I am looking for a method to replace the whole line which contains a specific phrase. 
For example the string looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Suspendisse egestas.
```

So I would like to find a method to replace the whole line that contains for example phrase `elit` with the new line `enim vehicula pellentesque.` so the resoult would be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
enim vehicula pellentesque. 
Suspendisse egestas.
```

Is there a quick way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "  Is there a quick way to do it
 " ?

Comment: Please see http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html , a bit outdated but still very relevant site. Spend time there and you will be better programmer. And not just in C# ...

Comment: @mitch wheat: as opposed to slow way maybe lol :)

Comment: Its already there on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014671/delete-lines-from-beginning-of-multiline-textbox-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^.*\Welit\W.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string result = regex.Replace(original, "enim vehicula pellentesque.");
```

`RegexOptions.Multiline` is key; it says to apply `^`, ( = "beginning") and `$` ( = "end") to mean beginning and end of line, instead of beginning and end of string.

The `\W`s look for non-word characters on either side of `elit`, so e.g. `fooelit` will not match but `foo elit` will.

Comment: You could use `\b` instead of `\W`.

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking to replace all lines that contain that *text*, you could do:

```
textBox.Lines = textBox.Lines
                       .Select(line => line.Contains("elit") 
                               ? "enim vehicula pellentesque." : line)
                       .ToArray();
```

If you're dealing with just the  string representing the lines, you could do something along the lines of:

```
string text = ...

var lines = from line in text.Split
                 (new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            select line.Contains("elit") ? "enim vehicula pellentesque." : line;

string replacedText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray());
```

**EDIT**:
As JG points out in a comment, this won't work if  you're looking for the specific *word* `elit`. In this case, you'll need a different predicate than a simple `string.Contains`. For example, you could  just split the line by all whitespace characters and check if one of them is the blacklisted word:

```
line.Split().Contains("elit") // pseudo-overload of String.Split
```

You may need a fancier filter (Regex such as in Domenic's answer) depending on your definition of 'word'.

Comment: #wow i was writing the usual foreach.. A good use of LINQ i have ever seen

Comment: Though this will also erroneously replace a line containing `elite`, for example.

Comment: @JG: very true. but have you noted that OP wanted to delete the line containing "elit." and not "elit"?

Comment: @yetanothercoder: Yes, but that is still the *word* `elit`. A simple way to detect it would be to use regex word boundaries (e.g., `@"\belit\b"`). Aside from this problem, which won't probably occur often if the OP is effectively dealing with latin phrases, this is a great answer and a *very* good use case for LINQ imho.

Comment: @JG: Thanks for the `elite` comment; I've tried to address that with an edit. Not sure if that's what the OP really wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        foreach (var line in textBox1.Lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("hello"))
            {
               textBox1.Text= textBox1.Text.Replace(line, "This is new line");
            }
        }
    }
```